# Elegant proof for $xy < yx \Leftrightarrow x^\mathbb{N} < y^\mathbb{N}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, combinatorics-on-words

Let $x, y$ be finite words over totally ordered alphabet and $<$ denote the lexicographical order, i.e for two not necessarily finite words we say $x < y$ iff one of the following holds

1. There are words $u, x^\prime, y^\prime$ and letters $a < b$ such that $x = uax^\prime, y = uby^\prime$
2. $y = xu$ for some non-empty word $u$

Then the following are equivalent

1. $xy < yx$
2. $x^\mathbb{N} < y^\mathbb{N}$, where $x^\mathbb{N}$ denotes infinite word $xxxx\ldots$

---

$x <^* y$ iff $xy < yx$ is a total order(which we're trying to prove by equivalence)

This new total order is another extension of "weak lexicographical order" where only first condition considered, i.e $x$ and $xu$ are incomparable for non-empty $u$(note that $xy$ and $yx$ always have the same length so we're not using "strong" order). It is naturally arising from the following problem:

> Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be finite words on totally ordered alphabet, find $\sigma \in S_n$ minimizing $x_{\sigma(1)}x_{\sigma(2)}\ldots x_{\sigma(n)}$

The solution is to sort $x_i$ with respect to order $<^*$. If the sequence is not sorted according to this order, then there are adjacent elements $x, y$ such that $xy > yx$, by swapping them we'll decrease word which we are minimizing.

But it might be tedious to prove that $<^*$ is transitive, so instead I suggest equivalent definition of $<^*$, that is $x <^* y$ iff $x^\mathbb{N} < y^\mathbb{N}$. Now transitivity is obvious.

But is there elegant and simple proof of equivalence not involving much of casework on $|x| <> |y|$, etc?

Comment: Note sure if this elegant enough, but observe that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the inequality $xy < yx$ implies that $$x^ny^n < y^nx^n$$
by repeatedly swapping pairs of $x$ and $y$. It follows that $x^\mathbb{N} \leq y^\mathbb{N}$. Note that inequality can only hold if the basic period of the infinite word divides both $x$ and $y$, in which case we would have $xy = yx$.

Comment: @1001 yes, I think it's elegant enough, in some sense your claim is taking limit of both sides $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x^ny^n = x^\mathbb{N}$.

You can post an answer if you prove 2 -> 1 too, your comment just proves 1 -> 2

Comment: But 2->1 follows from this: if 1 does not hold, then $xy\ge yx$, hence $x^ny^n\ge y^nx^n$ and taking the limit in $n$ we see that 2 also does not hold

Comment: Technically you didn't define the $<$ order on infinite words.

Comment: @SamHopkins If I'm not mistaken $<$ order on infinite words is defined purely by first condition and is total. Either two infinite words are equal, or we can take a look at first difference and compare letters, of course words $x^\prime, y^\prime$ are infinite in this case. Maybe it should be stressed that $u$ is finite.

Comment: 1 and 2 are only equivalent if $x$ is nonempty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $x, y \in \Sigma^+$.

Observe that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the inequality $xy<yx$ implies that $$x^ny^n<y^nx^n$$ by repeatedly swapping pairs of $x$ and $y$. It follows that $x^\mathbb{N}\leq y^\mathbb{N}$ (i.e. the two infinite sequences are equal, or $y^\mathbb{N}$ is greater at the first position they differ). Note that equality can only hold if the basic period of the infinite word divides both $|x|$ and $|y|$, in which case we would have $xy=yx$.

Conversely, $xy \geq yx$ implies $x^\mathbb{N} \geq y^\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You need $x$ to be nonempty in the converse argument.